# Dynamic Creation of Hash-Table and binding it to ASP-DataGrid using LINQ queries in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework, hashtable

This is what I done so far (Code Snippet)

ASP.NET markup:

```
 <div class="Grid-style">
   <asp:GridView ID="dgRequiredAttachment" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Key">
      <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Key" datafield="Key" SortExpression="Key" Visible="false"/>
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Value" datafield="Value" SortExpression="Value"/>
       </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
 </div>
```

VB.NET code:

```
 Protected Sub ddlCitizenStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlCitizenStatus.SelectedIndexChanged
Dim context As New EGrantsModel.Entities
Dim attachmentType As New EGrantsModel.ATTACHMNTTYPE

Dim DC As Hashtable = New Hashtable
Dim orderCopyDesc As String = (From orderCopy In context.ATTACHMNTTYPEs Where orderCopy.ATTACHTYPEID = "1" Select orderCopy.DESCRIPTION).First
Dim notificationLtrDesc As String = (From notificationLetter In context.ATTACHMNTTYPEs Where notificationLetter.ATTACHTYPEID = "2" Select notificationLetter.DESCRIPTION).First
Dim citizenListDesc As String = (From citizenList In context.ATTACHMNTTYPEs Where citizenList.ATTACHTYPEID = "3" Select citizenList.DESCRIPTION).First

DC.Add("1", orderCopyDesc)
DC.Add("2", notificationLtrDesc)
DC.Add("3", citizenListDesc) 

dgRequiredAttachment.DataSource = DC
dgRequiredAttachment.DataBind()
dgRequiredAttachment.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Now at the line

```
Dim DC As New Hashtable = New Hashtable
```

I want to: as you can see that I am creating the HashTable dynamically using LINQ queries. But if I have more than 3 entries in `Attachment` type table then, it will check all the values from `ATTACHMENTType` table as per `AttachmenttypeID` and populate/add items to hashtable using loop.

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the following code I solved my problem

**VB Code**

```
     Dim DC As Hashtable = New Hashtable
     Dim attachmentTypes = (From attachmentTypeData In context.ATTACHMNTTYPEs Select attachmentTypeData.DESCRIPTION, attachmentTypeData.ATTACHTYPEID)

       For Each a In attachmentTypes
         DC.Add(a.ATTACHTYPEID, a.DESCRIPTION)
       Next

      dgRequiredAttachment.DataSource = DC 
      dgRequiredAttachment.DataBind()
      dgRequiredAttachment.Visible = True
```